# Services not accesible from K8s node (MetalLB Layer2)

Tags: kubernetes, vsphere, kube-proxy, metallb, bare-metal-server

I have bare-metal deployed Kubernetes cluster on VMware vSphere private cloud.

Spec:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 [Cloud Image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/) (Also trying 18.04 and 21.04)
- Kubernetes: 1.23.1 (Also trying 1.21.8) - depolyed with kubeadm and kube-proxy (with strictARP and ipvs mode)
- CRI: Docker 20.10.12
- MetalLB v0.11.0 (Layer 2 mode)
- Cilium 1.11.1
- **All nodes in 192.168.50.0/24 subnet**

When I simply add deployment:
`kubectl create deployment nginx --image k8s.gcr.io/nginx:latest`

And exposed it:
`kubectl expose deployment nginx --type=LoadBalancer --port=80`

All seems good. Service got ExternalIP from MetalLB pool:
`nginx  LoadBalancer  10.96.56.118  198.168.50.152  80:32325/TCP  4s`

New ip address published on kube-ipvs0 interface:

> kube-ipvs0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
> ...
> inet 198.168.50.152/32 scope global kube-ipvs0
> valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
> ...

But I cant get access to service from all K8s nodes trought ExternalIP, and also from other LAN, curl returns:
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.50.152 port 80: No route to host`

ClusterIP works good, I can access it from node.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:
Your Virtual Machines and services must be in different subnets. In my case I have 192.168.50.0/24 network and I split it to 2 subnets 192.168.50.0/25 - for virtual machines and 192.168.50.128/25 for MetalLB services.